# calling external js twice

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, external

Is it possible to use external js files and jquery twice on the one html doc? I have the first one running but the second time it calls it doesn't work. Also the external js doesn't work when opened in Internet Explorer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/stylesheetelaine.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 




<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"> </script>

<script src="js/jQuery/jquery.monte.js"></script>     



<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gallery</title>


</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="title">

<h1><a href="index.html"><img src="img/elaine4.png"  width="517" height="185" alt="elaine cullinan"></a><img src="img/elainefilligree.png" width="235" height="251" alt="elaine"></h1>


<div id="nav">
<ul id>

<li><a href="about.html" title="About">About</a></li>
<li><a href="tattoo.html" title="Tattoo">Tattoo</a></li>
<li><a href="makeup.html" title="Make Up">Make Up</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html" title="Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="gallback">

<h2> Tattoos </h2>

<div id="gallerywrap">

    <div id='example1' class='container'>
        <img src="img/tattoogallery/outlineariel.jpg" alt='Zombie Ariel.'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/horsecar.jpg" alt='Elaine tattooing'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/2small.jpg" alt='Two Small Tattoos'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/clown.jpg" alt='Clown'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/lightsabers.jpg" alt='Finger Lightsabers'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/flouder.jpg" alt='Flounder'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/grenade.jpg" alt='Grenade'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/colourcherryblossom.jpg" alt='Colour Cherry Blossom'/>
   <img src="img/tattoogallery/13.jpg" alt='13'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/mechwing.jpg" alt='Mechanical Wing'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/qotsa.jpg" alt='QOTSA'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/horsecartatt.jpg" alt='Carousel'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/lovefinger.jpg" alt='Love finger tatt'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/hakun.jpg" alt='Hakuna Matata'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/romannum.jpg" alt='Roman Numerals'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/slayer.jpg" alt='Slayer'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/shamrock.jpg" alt='Shamrock'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/scriptarm.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/skull.jpg" alt='Skull'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/wristfoot.jpg" alt='Wrist and Foot Tatts'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/zombieariel.jpg" alt='Zombie Ariel'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/script.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/chinese.jpg" alt='Chinese Symbols'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/colflower.jpg" alt='Flower'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/scriptfoot.jpg" alt='Foot Script Tatt'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/Triton.jpg" alt='Triton'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/zombiefingers.jpg" alt='Zombie Finger Tatt'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/tyler.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/3ursula.jpg" alt='Ursula'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/locket.jpg" alt='Locket'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/mechwing2.jpg" alt='Mechanical Wings'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/backscript.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/wingcolor.jpg" alt='Coloured Wing'/>


    </div>

 </div>


</div>


<div id="gallback">

<h2> Make Up </h2>

<div id="gallerywrap">

    <div id='example1' class='container'>
        <img src="img/tattoogallery/outlineariel.jpg" alt='Zombie Ariel.'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/horsecar.jpg" alt='Elaine tattooing'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/2small.jpg" alt='Two Small Tattoos'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/clown.jpg" alt='Clown'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/lightsabers.jpg" alt='Finger Lightsabers'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/flouder.jpg" alt='Flounder'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/grenade.jpg" alt='Grenade'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/colourcherryblossom.jpg" alt='Colour Cherry Blossom'/>



    </div>

</div>


</div>



</div>
</body>

</html>
```

external:

```
        $(function () {
            // Unstyled Example
            $.monte('#example1');


            // Styled Buttons Example
            // (see the CSS in the above style block)
            $.monte('#example2', {auto:false});


            // Callback Example
            // Format and append the HTML:
            $('#example3 > img').each(function(){
                $(this)
                .wrap('<div style="position:relative"/>')
                .parent()
                .append('<div><p>' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</p></div>')
                .append('<img src="frame.png" alt="" class="frame"/>');
            });
            // Hide the text on all but the center slide:
            $('#example3 div div').css({opacity: 0}).eq(0).css({opacity: 0.8});
            // Using the callbacks to reveal and hide the text:
            $.monte('#example3', {
                auto:false,
                callbackIn: function () {
                    $(this[0]).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8}, 450);
                }, 
                callbackAway: function () {
                    $(this[0]).find('div').animate({opacity: 0}, 450);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Call me crazy but I can only see 3 JS files each included 1 time. If your question is whether or not you can include more than 1 external JS file, then the answer is yes. Very much so. Else most pages now-a-days wouldn't have a chance. Are you sure your files are uploaded?

Comment: You want to run something from the javascript? Where is the javascript being executed? I might be missing something.

Comment: Please post some of the javascript, I don't understand what you're trying to call multiple times. I see the includes, but not anywhere that explicitly calling JavaScript into action. Are they being called in the external files ? Please provide some code/context, thanks.

Comment: Sorry I should be more clear. The 3 js files are being called in the **div id=example1** to create a slider. I've called it (div id=example1) again below that, but it doesn't work

Comment: I think I answered it, try renaming the ID and calling it again, otherwise it's like using the same phone number to call 2 different people, it's not going to work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make multiple DOM objects with the same ID. ID's are supposed to be unique identifiers. When you use the same ID multiple times, it's most likely to only work on the first object with the same ID.

Rename the ID and call it with the new ID.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>

<link href="css/stylesheetelaine.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 




<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"> </script>

<script src="js/jQuery/jquery.monte.js"></script>     



<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Gallery</title>


</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="title">

<h1><a href="index.html"><img src="img/elaine4.png"  width="517" height="185" alt="elaine cullinan"></a><img src="img/elainefilligree.png" width="235" height="251" alt="elaine"></h1>


<div id="nav">
<ul id>

<li><a href="about.html" title="About">About</a></li>
<li><a href="tattoo.html" title="Tattoo">Tattoo</a></li>
<li><a href="makeup.html" title="Make Up">Make Up</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html" title="Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="gallback">

<h2> Tattoos </h2>

<div id="gallerywrap">

    <div id='example1' class='container'>
        <img src="img/tattoogallery/outlineariel.jpg" alt='Zombie Ariel.'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/horsecar.jpg" alt='Elaine tattooing'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/2small.jpg" alt='Two Small Tattoos'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/clown.jpg" alt='Clown'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/lightsabers.jpg" alt='Finger Lightsabers'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/flouder.jpg" alt='Flounder'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/grenade.jpg" alt='Grenade'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/colourcherryblossom.jpg" alt='Colour Cherry Blossom'/>
   <img src="img/tattoogallery/13.jpg" alt='13'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/mechwing.jpg" alt='Mechanical Wing'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/qotsa.jpg" alt='QOTSA'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/horsecartatt.jpg" alt='Carousel'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/lovefinger.jpg" alt='Love finger tatt'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/hakun.jpg" alt='Hakuna Matata'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/romannum.jpg" alt='Roman Numerals'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/slayer.jpg" alt='Slayer'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/shamrock.jpg" alt='Shamrock'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/scriptarm.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/skull.jpg" alt='Skull'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/wristfoot.jpg" alt='Wrist and Foot Tatts'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/zombieariel.jpg" alt='Zombie Ariel'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/script.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/chinese.jpg" alt='Chinese Symbols'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/colflower.jpg" alt='Flower'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/scriptfoot.jpg" alt='Foot Script Tatt'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/Triton.jpg" alt='Triton'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/zombiefingers.jpg" alt='Zombie Finger Tatt'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/tyler.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/3ursula.jpg" alt='Ursula'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/locket.jpg" alt='Locket'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/mechwing2.jpg" alt='Mechanical Wings'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/backscript.jpg" alt='Script'/>

   <img src="img/tattoogallery/wingcolor.jpg" alt='Coloured Wing'/>


    </div>

 </div>


</div>


<div id="gallback">

<h2> Make Up </h2>

<div id="gallerywrap2">

    <div id='example2' class='container'>
        <img src="img/tattoogallery/outlineariel.jpg" alt='Zombie Ariel.'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/horsecar.jpg" alt='Elaine tattooing'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/2small.jpg" alt='Two Small Tattoos'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/clown.jpg" alt='Clown'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/lightsabers.jpg" alt='Finger Lightsabers'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/flouder.jpg" alt='Flounder'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/grenade.jpg" alt='Grenade'/>

        <img src="img/tattoogallery/colourcherryblossom.jpg" alt='Colour Cherry Blossom'/>



    </div>

</div>


</div>



</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Under the makeup section I renamed it to Gallery2 under gallerwrap2. For the unstyled example you should call  `$.monte('#example2');`

Comment: Thank you, it works! Kind of messed up the layout but should be easy to sort. Is there a reason for it all not working in IE though?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? Do you get any sort of script errors?

Comment: Sorry! Blonde Moment! I just remembered I fixed it earlier, I hadn't closed a div, it worked in other browsers but not IE. Thanks again

Comment: @user1944305 groovy. Some browsers are more forgiving than others. Good luck!

Comment: @user1944305 . You can use this site: http://lint.brihten.com/html/ to check for some obvious HTML errors. It will point out tags that need to be closed etc.